# iPhone - having selected cell move to top of uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

I looked for this problem and I don't believe I could find an answer. I have a tableview of custom cells that when clicked, the selected cell pushes a new cell with information. I was wondering if anyone had an idea of how to push the selected cell to the top of the uitableview, or make it fill up the entire tableview.

My uitableview only takes up half of the screen, and I wish for when the cell is selected that it only take up that half of the screen, and the user is still able to scroll the cell (if that makes sense)?

Any suggestions would be appreciated, it was somewhat difficult to describe what I am looking for, so if anyone needs clarification please do not hesitate to ask me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you need to place this in after you have created your cell

```
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

This did the trick for me with the custom height of the cells as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my app I have a bunch of cells that expand to be larger when clicked; and only 1 cell can be expanded at a time. I basically keep track of the current selected indexPath, and then in heightForRowAtIndexPath: check to see if this is the selected sell; if it is I return a larger height.

Then, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: I just set the current indexPath, and reload both the new cell and the previous one. This sounds similar to what you are looking for... would that work?

Answer (score 0):

To move the selected cell to the top of the tableview, you could store the selected cell's index in an instance variable in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and then call [tableView reloadData].

In your datasource's tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, you would ensure that the selected cell is returned for index 0 and all cells prior to the selected cell are returned for their index + 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to move the cell, this is a base you could start from.

```
-(void)moveIndexPathToTop:(NSIndexPath *)pathToMove
{
     [myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:pathToMove] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     NSIndexPath *firstRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
     [myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:firstRow] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

This will move the row as far as the UITableView is conserned. Of course you'll need to match the new order in the data source also. (Like changing the order in your array of data)

Also, you'll probably want to scroll the table to the top when you do this.

Comment: how would I move the cell back to where it was when it is deselected?