# particular section should go to the top of the tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a `UITableview` where I use `viewForHeaderInSection` method to customize the view like a drop down so when I select the particular button on the section header view the cell for row appears like a drop down. I need a way such that when I select the particular section this section should go to the top of the tableview.

Is there a solution to implement this?

Comment: nice question but what you have to tried ??? follow https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441922/if-we-click-on-custom-section-header-in-uitableview-then-move-that-section-to-t Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353680/iphone-having-selected-cell-move-to-top-of-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

First of all get section based on dropdown selection.

```
CGRect rect = [tableView rectForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section];

[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, rect.origin.y)
             animated:YES];  

[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section]                                                
               atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                       animated:YES];
```